# Determine type of the hash algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, hash, openssl, checksum, sha

I am trying to create a program that prints the given hash as input.

Example: myprogram.exe
`04033ca1921e1d4ab6c4036401786c18d97dca5ea4f886b95ae92d4e3423fffe0045071b97cdd00df725611d757d1ca756ab325230a7faeead09385663a29ae2`

Output: Hash algorithm: SHA512

myprogram.exe
`86896e2eb7ea8ce15c3037d4d59e2f5f505d28588b413b48499d54f6d83b877fc01512aac7c98f28bb2ef3f0b7ddd5e740ae3146d13385efe1bc67f00721c951`

Output: Hash algorithm: SHA3-512

myprogram.exe
`c872e20ea321f223c531c03a37b58c51`

Output: Hash algorithm: MD5

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

std::string determineHashAlgorithm(const std::string& hash) {
    const EVP_MD* md = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA256");
    if (md == nullptr) {
        return "Unknown";
    }

    EVP_MD_CTX* mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, nullptr);
    unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    unsigned int md_len;
    EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, hash.c_str(), hash.length());
    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(mdctx);

    if (md_len == hash.length() && memcmp(md_value, hash.c_str(), md_len) == 0) {
        return EVP_MD_name(md);
    }

    return "Unknown";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <hash>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string hash = argv[1];
    std::string algorithm = determineHashAlgorithm(hash);

    std::cout << "Hash algorithm: " << algorithm << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And it says: Hash algorithm: unknown every time, no mater the hash you give as input.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is not what these EVP functions do. They ***calculate*** a ***specific*** hash that ***you*** specify. That is, you specify whether you want to calculate an MD5 hash, a SHA1, hash, or a SHA256 hash, of ***something***. Then you specify the ***something***. And then these functions calculate the hash. There is no OpenSSL function that attempts to figure out what random hash was used to compute a hash of some unknown piece of data. In fact, this may not be always mathematically possible to do.

Comment: All that you can tell in general about a string of hex characters is the bit length,  You can guess it is MD5 or SHA-1/2 by the length and them being the most common hash methods but it is still just guessing.   It might not even be a hash, just binary data.  Also, hashes are one-way and lossy so you can't then "decrypt" the hash.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What makes you classify the first as `SHA512` and the second as `SHA3-512`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I generated it using a hashing website you van find on google. What you mean?

Comment: So you _know_ that the first is generated with SHA512 and the second with SHA3-512 already? Ok... I thought that was what your program had guessed.

Comment: Yes, but how to make the program to "know" which one is which? I need an algorithm for that.

Comment: If the hash algorithms are any good, you can't know. You would need to know the cleartext input, hash it with all the possible algorithms and see if you get the same hash value with any of them.

Comment: Who gave you this _Hard task™_ ? Why do you _need_ to be able to do this?

Comment: Hard doesn't come close to describing the difficulty.

Comment: "To help me with this assignment, please also provide me with a quantum computer"